# Goquery loads empty document from distinctly not empty response

Tags: go, goquery

I've been trying to load a response into a goquery document, but it appears to be failing (though it throws no errors).

The response I'm trying to load comes from:

```
https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search_api_ajax/search/recipes?sort=created&order=desc&page=4
```

and while it doesn't throw any errors, when I call `fmt.Println(goquery.OuterHtml(doc.Contents()))` I get the output:

```
<html><head></head><body></body></html>
```

Meanwhile, If I don't attempt to load it into a goquery document, and instead call

```
s, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
fmt.Println(string(s))
```

I get:

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 no-touch" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js lt-ie9 no-touch" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]> <html class="no-js gt-ie-8 no-touch" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if !IE]><!-->
<html class="no-js no-touch" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Search | BBC Good Food</title>
    <!--[if IE]><![endif]-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <link rel="prev" href="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?page=3&amp;sort=created&amp;order=desc" />
    <link rel="next" href="https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search/recipes?page=5&amp;sort=created&amp;order=desc" />
    <meta name="robots" content="noindex" />
    <style>
        .async-hide {
            opacity: 0 !important
        }
    ... etc
```

The basic logic of what I'm doing is as follows:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery"
    "io/ioutil"
)

func main() {
    baseUrl := "https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/search_api_ajax/search/recipes?sort=created&order=desc&page="
    i := 4

    // Make a request
    req, _ := http.NewRequest(http.MethodGet, fmt.Sprintf("%s%d", baseUrl, i), nil)

    // Create a new HTTP client and execute the request
    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, _ := client.Do(req)

    // Print out response
    s, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(string(s))

    // Load into goquery doc
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)
    fmt.Println(goquery.OuterHtml(doc.Contents()))
}
```

The full response can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/alexskates/c64b903a4db42e806c3054f4488c8a9f). Is there any particular reason why this won't load?

Comment: Please show your actual code.

Comment: I have removed some of the logic (as the response occasionally comes back in JSON) but I've updated it to include a (complete) minimal example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go's html parser doesn't seem to like the html you're getting - the `<html>` tags are all within comments, so I think it's just never getting going on the parsing.

If you prepend the document with `<html>` everything works fine from there. One way to do that would be with a reader-wrapper, something like the following, which writes the html tag the first time `Read` is called and delegates to `resp.Body` on subsequent calls.

```golang
import "io"

var htmlTag string = "<html>\n"

type htmlAddingReader struct {
    sentHtml bool
    source io.Reader
}

func (r *htmlAddingReader) Read(b []byte) (n int, err error) {
    if !r.sentHtml {
        copy(b, htmlTag)
        r.sentHtml = true
        return len(htmlTag), nil
    } else {
        return r.source.Read(b)
    }
}
```

To use this in your sample code, change the final section like so:

```golang
    // Load into goquery doc
    wrapped := &htmlAddingReader{}
    wrapped.source = resp.Body
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(wrapped)
    fmt.Println(goquery.OuterHtml(doc.Contents()))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two issues with the code:

(1) [`resp.Body`](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Response.Body) is an [`io.ReadCloser`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadCloser) stream.

[`ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)`](https://pkg.go.dev/io#ReadAll) reads the whole stream, so there is nothing left for [`goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(resp.Body)`](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery#example-NewDocumentFromReader-String) to read, so it returns an empty doc.

Instead, you can use [`NewReader(s)`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#NewReader) to create a new stream from the saved body string.

(2) `doc.Contents()` returns the children of the top element which is just `<!DOCTYPE html>`.  If you want the whole doc, then you probably want to use `doc.Selection`.

Something like this should work:

```golang
    // Read entire resp.Body into raw
    raw, _ := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    s := string(raw)

    // Print out response
    fmt.Println(s)

    // Create a new readable stream with NewReader(s)
    doc, _ := goquery.NewDocumentFromReader(strings.NewReader(s))
    
    // Use doc.Selection to get the whole doc
    fmt.Println(doc.Selection.Html())
```